# Upgrade/port Webforms website to newer MS technology

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webforms, blazor

I've been researching for a few hours but because I'm late to the game a lot of what I find are old q&a's (7+ yrs old) so I figured I'd lean on this community for some current guidance.

More than 10 years ago I inherited and continue to build and maintain an ASP.NET WebForms website (not application) critical to our organization. It is a reasonably large site coming in at around 400 aspx pages (but only 200+ appear to be regularly used anymore).
In that solution are 3 projects: the first being the website, and the other two projects are just code (the business and data layers).

We are a manufacturer, and the site tracks the parts we build, the orders we receive, generates invoices, schedules and tracks production, material usage, etc. The point is it's a boring corporate app that doesn't require any flashy client-side features; its almost entirely forms to get info, and grids of data for reporting with the occasional chart thrown in. LOTS of business logic, though!

We need to upgrade/replace the **WebForms** website in more modern technology(s). We are a Microsoft shop and I'd be the only developer working on this. I have a DevExpress universal subscription which has proven invaluable. It appears **MVC** is a no-go because "it is no longer in active development". **Blazor** and its SPA doesn't seem like an appropriate technology to migrate to when I've got such a large website. So I feel like I'm left with **Razor**. Am I on the right track here?

Comment: If it's a corporate web site, you can use Blazor Server App. Why do you think Blazor is not appropriate technology to migrate to ? Anyhow, Razor Pages App can be a good candidate for that.

Comment: Why do you _"need to upgrade/replace"_ ?  MS will support it as part of .net4.8 for many years to come.

Comment: Blazor Server-side is a perfect fit to replace a WebForms app. Even MS says so: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/blazor-for-web-forms-developers/ and there are controls that help too https://github.com/FritzAndFriends/BlazorWebFormsComponents

Comment: @enet thank you for your answer. to answer your question, when I was reading about Blazor and the SPA concept, it didn't feel suited for my hundreds of pages website. Clearly just me not fully understanding SPA.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I recognize it'll be supported for many years, but it might take that long to migrate to something current. Also, I'm constantly building new sites/solutions at work and I'd like to choose the technology now and start learning it

Comment: @PTansey, your question is opinion-based, depending on the view held by the answerer and his knowledge... However, I'd advise you to learn how to create Razor Pages App applications as well as related subjects. I'd suggest you to migrate to CSharp, and then start learning Blazor. With Blazor you can create different kind of applications, including ones that run on the desktops , hybrid apps, and you can even use  Razor Pages App to create a web site which host Razor components (Blazor components). That is the path you should take.

Comment: It is very opinionated. Blazor is still very new an although an official product it could become "no longer actively developed" too. On the whole it may even have less long term support than WebForms. But any pick will have that risk.

Comment: I fear Blazor might be the new Silverlight but that's the risk as Henk pointed out. Sorry if my question is "opinion-based", as I mentioned I'm really out of the loop and trying to understand Razor vs Blazor and the SPA concept throws me.
I'm so very grateful for everyone's comments. Not sure why there isn't an answer for me to mark as "the answer", I'm not terribly experienced with Stackoverlow either, apparently. <embarassed eyeroll>

Comment: Some (slightly dated) advice here, be sure to find the eBook: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears Blazor is a perfectly good replacement for my large Webforms solution. I got tripped up with ignorance around what a SPA (single page application) is all about (especially since I didn't get experience with routing while in Webforms and I'm leapfrogging MVC where I expect the concept was introduced). I'd have marked someone else's comment as an answer if I could.

Answer (score 1):

What I did for my old ASP.NET site is to create a subdomain in IIS for the Blazor stuff, and to move things over section by section.  That way, I didn't have to re-create hundreds of pages before users could start benefitting from the improvements in responsiveness.